# setting a string's char' by index

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList of strings, and I want to randomly change a string's (random) char' by index.

ArrayListName.get(i).charAt(j)

exists. What's the equiv' for a setter?

Comment: Strings are immutable, so you'd have to allocate a new String for that. Is that okay for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are immutable so they can't change. You can use a `StringBuffer` or `Character Array`. `StringBuffer` has a `setCharAt` method that takes an index and character.

If you want to use a `String` you'll have to create a new `String` with the character changed and replace the old `String`.

Answer (score 0):

`String` is immutable.  If you want to change the specific location's string, then you would want to use [`String.replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and capture the results in your `ArrayList`.